# An alternative to data processing inside callback functions?

Tags: ros, callback, subscribe, spin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to perform calculations on the data from my subscriptions the instant it arrives.
I could of course just do this inside the callback function, but i would insted like to perform these calculations outside of the callback function, right after it has returned.
The callback function will then just pass the data to a queue which another function will use for processing.

My question is then: How can this be achieved?.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227483/an-alternative-to-data-processing-inside-callback-functions?/) by [ros_geller](https://answers.ros.org/users/23660/ros_geller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2016-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Edit:** now I see that I **can** edit my answer, oops. Please make sure and read mitch722 's answer below! Original answer follows:

By moving the calculations outside of the callback (recommended, of course!), you're explicitly decoupling calculations from the callback mechanism, thereby **necessarily** losing the ability to begin processing the "instant it arrives". With that said, what you probably desire is an *event system* (that operates with its own event queue, not simply a subsidiary function callback). That's beyond the scope of this answer.

What you could do instead -- much easier, but likely uses a bit more CPU and is a bit less responsive -- is to use a combination of [ROS Timer](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Timers) and your own data queue. In your data callback, put the data in your queue; in the timer callback, process an (likely all) element that is in the queue (if none, just return).

Note that by using a `Timer`, you're utilizing the ROS callback system. Assuming single threaded spinning, there's no need to worry about data synchronization. But note also that a typical `spin()` will process **all** messages in the callback queue, so special measures would need to be taken to process one message at a time (e.g., guarantee that there will always be a timer event between queued data messages).

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2016-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-25**:
Wouldn't simply pushing the incoming message into an application/node level queue and then assigning that queue to a (pool of) worker threads give you that "*event system*"? That isn't too complicated, and you also don't need to resort to implementing a polling system as you describe.

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2016-02-26**:
Yes, as you say, that's effectively an *event system* as I used the term. With no language specified, I assume C++, so shy away from recommending multi-threading. Plus, it still seems to me that a `Timer` of high enough frequency is the easiest method, albeit not the most efficient/timely.

**Comment by [ros_geller](https://answers.ros.org/users/23660/ros_geller/) on 2016-03-01**:
Sorry for the late response: I am using C++, yes. After thinking about it, what I think i need here is something like a producer-consumer design. So I'm now wondering if there are ROS native functionalities to do this or if i have to do it from scratch? I should prob go read up on the design pattern

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2016-03-02**:
What I described **is** a producer-consumer. The publisher is the producer, the timer callback is the consumer. The issues are the delay and interleaving message reception/processing. Y'know, if polling is a concern, you could add a one-shot timer in the message callback.